# How to get sharedPreferences in Application

Tags: android

I have implemented a configuration that uses `PreferenceFragment`:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.game_prefs);
```

Now I want to handle upgrade process, so I started to implement a procedure in `android.app.Application` subclass.

The issue is that I do not know how to get correct prefs instance.

There is no name in Fragment:

```
getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

But prefs name is mandatory here in App subclass:

```
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(XX,mode)
```

Where can I get correct name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) developer guide

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String syncConnPref = sharedPref.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_SYNC_CONN, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the activity, you can get it from getPreferences().

More information found here:

Saving Key-Value Sets
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

getPreferences is used when you do not store it to a specific file name.

Comment: Application is not a activity.